# What algorithm does Pandas use for computing variance?

Tags: python, r, algorithm, pandas, statistics

Which method does Pandas use for computing the variance of a Series?

For example, using Pandas (v0.14.1):

```
pandas.Series(numpy.repeat(500111,2000000)).var()
12.579462289731145
```

Obviously due to some numeric instability.  However, in R we get:

```
var(rep(500111,2000000))
0
```

I wasn't able to make enough sense of the Pandas source-code to figure out what algorithm it uses.
This link may be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance

**Update**: To summarize the comments below - If the Python [bottleneck](http://berkeleyanalytics.com/bottleneck/) package for fast NumPy array functions is installed, a stabler two-pass algorithm similar to `np.sqrt(((arr - arr.mean())**2).mean())` is used and gives 0.0 (as indicated by @Jeff); whereas if it is not installed, the naive implementation indicated by @BrenBarn is used.

Comment: What is the `repeat` function you are using in Python?

Comment: @BrenBarn it is the numpy.repeat function

Comment: show your pandas version. as of 0.14.1 this will also return 0.0

Comment: @Jeff - I'm using Pandas v0.14.1 and numpy 1.8.0 (on Win7) and getting the answer indicated in the Q.

Comment: see my comment, do you have ``bottleneck`` installed?

Comment: @Jeff - didn't have bottleneck installed (has never heard of it).  Now I have installed it and it does indeed return 0.0 now.  I'd consider that a Pandas bug that we can get two differing answers from the same core function depending on if a 3rd-party package is installed or not

Comment: Its already marked as an issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7900; the numerical instability is due to the naive implementation of the algorithm. for example, rolling_var has already been fixed for this. pull requests are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm can be seen in `nanops.py`, in the function `nanvar`, the last line of which is:

```
return np.fabs((XX - X ** 2 / count) / d)
```

This is the "naive" implementation at the beginning of the Wikipedia article you mention.  (`d` will be set to N-1 in the default case.)

The behavior you're seeing appears to be due to the sum of squared values overflowing the numpy datatypes.  It's not an issue of how the variance is calculated per se.

Comment: But, if you have ``bottleneck`` install that will be used instead!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, but it seems related to how `Series` are stored, not necessarily the `var` function.

```
np.var(pd.Series(repeat(100000000,100000)))
26848.788479999999

np.var(repeat(100000000,100000))
0.0
```

Using Pandas 0.11.0.